# What linux distribution should I virtualize from windows host to run Eclipse?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, virtualization

I need to use Eclipse on a Linux Virtual Box virtualization, Windows XP host, on a laptop. I don't know the specs of that laptop, but it's less than 2 years old.
My first choice of Linux distribution is Ubuntu, but I've heard that in Ubuntu, Eclipse is can be bugged or slow. I don't mind if it's slow. I only need to know if there is a risk that it might not work, since I have a limited time to install and try that.
I would also like to know about any other linux distribution that does or does not work fine for you with Eclipse.
Note: I only need to build a C++ project.

Comment: I've been using eclipse on ubuntu for nearly two years; for me, it works fine. As you only need it for C++ project just use eclipse cdt. http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

Comment: It's in a virtual machine, not a simple Ubuntu install :).

Comment: yes, I understand that. I was just trying to clear his apprehension "I've heard that in Ubuntu, Eclipse is either bugged or slow"

Comment: OK, I'll edit that, sorry for the engrish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse runs on Java.

Any linux distro (apart from command line ones) will do.

If you like Ubuntu go with it!

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu will work just fine as an OS.  I use eclipse in Ubuntu running on a VM in a cloud somewhere.  So I can just remote desktop into it and pick up where I left off.

Comment: Wow, remote desktop programming is new for me. Flying VMs btw?

Comment: I typically just use screen or tmux and VIM as an editor.  I have one server that has about 10 screens with ssh connections to all my other servers.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu should be OK. Just make sure to use the Sun's official Java (its in the repository) and not the openjdk (which is the default). For what I hear, this may speedup the things a little bit.

Disclaimer: I did not try to replace java.

Answer (score 1):

I'd hesitate at suggesting a distro like Ubuntu for your machine -- look at something like Arch which is simple to setup and relatively lean.